# Why is the scaffold generating routes like this? Why do they work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

The book "Agile development with Rails" shows in the second chapter, that you can say:

```
<%= link_to "Goodbye",say_goodbye_path %>
```

Instead of hardcoding the path to "/say/goodbye". Makes sense, I thought to myself. Probably Ruby is splitting the `say_goodbye_path` by `_`, assigns the first part as the controller name, the second part as the action name. But, afterwards, I generated the following scaffold:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string mail:string
```

And I noticed in the `index.html.erb` view, that it had methods like: `edit_user_path(user)`. I tried to rewrite it to `user_edit_path(user)`, but of course, it didn't work. My question is, why are the scaffold links the other way around? How would I know if I should write them in the way the author uses them in `link_to`, or in the way they are generated by the scaffold. Can you shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The helper functions like `user_edit_path` are automatically generated by rails to map operations on resources to the matching routes and thus HTTP paths and HTTP verbs. You have to understand that you are dealing with resources here, not necessarily with simple controllers.

While most of the time your resources can map to a single controller, it doesn't have to be that way. You can have nested or combined resources which can result in rather complex routing definitions.

Resources are typically defined by giving it a name (`user`in this case) and defining some allowed operations on them. Rails encourages to follow the REST pattern there, so you can have shortcuts to have some operations pre-defined. One of them is `edit`, which by default matches to a GET request to users_controller#edit. Default operations on RAILS resources are:

```
HTTP verb  path          matching controller action
===================================================
GET        /users        #=> index
GET        /users/1      #=> show
GET        /users/new    #=> new
GET        /users/1/edit #=> edit
PUT        /users/1      #=> update
POST       /users        #=> create
DELETE     /users/1      #=> destroy
```

These mappings can be customized on your routes.rb (changing methods, adding or removing operations, ...) Generally you are encouraged to use the default mappings as these are supported by standard helpers and make your app easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Scaffolds are code generated by a template which is not related to the routing.

Routing is based on the `route.rb` in your config folder. All resources are routed by default (when generated by scaffolds) but there's a default rule `/:controller/:action/:id` that you can enable. Think of a "catch all" case.

One way to see what routes to have is to edit `route.rb` and run `rake routes` and see how they change. There's an official guide here too: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Ok, sure. But why is `edit_user_path(user)`, in my mind, is working like this: `ActionName_ControllerName_path`, and `link_to` is `ControllerName_ActionName_path`. Why aren't they the same way?

Comment: The link Zepplock posted explains how different types of routes work. Scaffolding uses resource routes and I'm assuming the example your book uses in chapter 2 is a non resource route. Read sections 2 and 3.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you get `ControllerName_ActionName_path` pattern from. If you run your `rake routes` you will see that name for every route is `ActionName_ControllerName` unless you hardcode it otherwise in your `routes.rb`. Hardcoding routes in not recommended unless you have cases when your model is `User` and you want it to appear like `Customer` in your URIs